# Bind Android Spinner with Http reponse data (json) in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin.android

i am learning xamarin android. I am stuck in something strange.

Normally i wanted to bind my android spinner with my json data which i pulled from my webapi. i wrote this block of code.

```
 var spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.RouteSelect);

        string url = "http://localhost/api/android/pullroutes";
        JsonValue json = await FetchWeatherAsync(url);
        string temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < json.Count; i++) {
            //temp += json[i]["name"].ToString();
            temp += json[i]["name"].ToString() ;
        }


        var items = new List<string>() { temp };
        var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);
        spinner.Adapter = adapter;
```

But it shows me data in spinner as text but not like drop down style.

[Android Spinner View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrjE3.png)

anything i wrote wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string temp = "";
ArrayList items = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < json.Count; i++) {
    temp = json[i]["name"].ToString();
    items.Add(temp);
}

var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);
spinner.Adapter = adapter;
```

You see the difference?
You have one LONG string in `temp` because you are doing `+=`.

Each `String` has to be added to the `ArrayList` as an item. What you have right now is a `List` with one item and that item contains a long string.

Note: I'm giving the answer based on Java. I understand this is Xamarin/C# but you should be able to do similar.

Comment: @th3par3l    Thanks for you Answer. 

'var items = new List<string>() { temp };' 
i wrote this line to add to list. Do i have to again add those to another array? 
Please help me understand clearly :)

Comment: @KhaledMd.TuhidulHossain what you are adding is one item to the list because `temp` is only one item. You have to create a new instance of it and add it to the list in the for loop. My example should work. try it out

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
```

and

```
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items);
```

found error from those 2 line.